# Exception while Testing SOA Composite Application

Tags: soap, weblogic, soa, jdeveloper

I am working on Oracle SOA Suite 11g, i am a beginner and following some labs, in which i am developing some SOA composite applications in JDeveloper 11g IDE. While testing a composite application using the Enterprise Manager of the WebLogic Server, i got the following exception:

The selected operation execute could not be invoked.

An exception occured while invoking the webservice operation. Please see logs for more details.

```
oracle.sysman.emSDK.webservices.wsdlapi.SoapTestException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.ContentTypeException: Not a valid SOAP Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8<br>

java.lang.Exception: oracle.sysman.emSDK.webservices.wsdlapi.SoapTestException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.ContentTypeException: Not a valid SOAP Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

    at oracle.sysman.emas.model.wsmgt.WSTestModel.invokeOperation(WSTestModel.java:813)
    at oracle.sysman.emas.view.wsmgt.WSView.invokeOperation(WSView.java:385)
    at oracle.sysman.emas.view.wsmgt.WSView.invokeOperation(WSView.java:302)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.util.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:53)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcastToMethodBinding(UIXComponentBase.java:1415)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:183)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:92)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:361)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:96)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:103)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:92)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:361)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:96)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:97)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:475)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:756)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:957)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:427)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:207)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.license.LicenseFilter.doFilter(LicenseFilter.java:101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.help.web.rich.OHWFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.sysman.emas.fwk.MASConnectionFilter.doFilter(MASConnectionFilter.java:41)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.AuditServletFilter.doFilter(AuditServletFilter.java:179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.EMRepLoginFilter.doFilter(EMRepLoginFilter.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.sysman.core.model.targetauth.EMLangPrefFilter.doFilter(EMLangPrefFilter.java:158)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.sysman.core.app.perf.PerfFilter.doFilter(PerfFilter.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.sysman.eml.app.ContextInitFilter.doFilter(ContextInitFilter.java:542)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3738)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3704)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: oracle.sysman.emSDK.webservices.wsdlapi.SoapTestException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.ContentTypeException: Not a valid SOAP Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.webservices.wsdlapi.dispatch.DispatchUtil.invoke(DispatchUtil.java:362)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.webservices.wsdlparser.OperationInfoImpl.invokeWithDispatch(OperationInfoImpl.java:1004)
    at oracle.sysman.emas.model.wsmgt.PortName.invokeOperation(PortName.java:750)
    at oracle.sysman.emas.model.wsmgt.WSTestModel.invokeOperation(WSTestModel.java:807)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.ContentTypeException: Not a valid SOAP Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:880)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.OracleDispatchImpl.synchronousInvocationWithRetry(OracleDispatchImpl.java:235)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.OracleDispatchImpl.invoke(OracleDispatchImpl.java:106)
    at oracle.sysman.emSDK.webservices.wsdlapi.dispatch.DispatchUtil.invoke(DispatchUtil.java:358)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.ContentTypeException: Not a valid SOAP Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call2(HttpSOAPConnection.java:231)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.common.transport.HttpTransport.transmit(HttpTransport.java:75)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.common.async.MessageSender.call(MessageSender.java:67)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.common.async.Transmitter.transmitSync(Transmitter.java:134)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.common.async.Transmitter.transmit(Transmitter.java:90)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.common.async.RequestorImpl.transmit(RequestorImpl.java:273)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.common.async.RequestorImpl.invoke(RequestorImpl.java:94)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:824)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.ContentTypeException: Not a valid SOAP Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createVersionedMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:281)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:173)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.getHttpResponseMessage(HttpSOAPConnection.java:766)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post2(HttpSOAPConnection.java:534)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection$PrivilegedPost.run(HttpSOAPConnection.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call2(HttpSOAPConnection.java:229)
    ... 92 more
```

i am stuck, can someone provide a clue?

Comment: Sounds like it should be text/xml not text/html. Maybe you are missing the xml header on the soap call? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SOAPUI pr TCPMonitor to analyze the communication between the Client and SOA server. This will tell you if you are sending `text/html` or `text/xml`.

Also, you should check the WSDL on the SOA server that corresponds to the servis you are testing, try accessing the `http://server:port/service?WSDL` to see what is really being deployed. You can also see this from the Test Console.

And then, verify the definition of the input interface of the composite in your BPEL editor (jDeveloper), see if it constraints the input format. It is a WebService-call interface, right?

Comment: I analyzed the service using SOAPUI and this is what i got: 500--Internal Server Error
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.WebServiceEntryBindingComponent$1.isConvertCDATA&#40;Ljava/lang/String&#59;&#41;Z
 at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.provider.ProviderPort.getConvertCData(ProviderPort.java:983)
 at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.WebServiceServlet.createSOAPMessageForPOST(WebServiceServlet.java:806)
 at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.WebServiceServlet.createSOAPMessageForPOST(WebServiceServlet.java:735)
 at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.WebServiceServlet.createSOAPMessage(WebServiceServlet